# How to differentiate vim terminal from regular terminal in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, vim

A recent release of vim introduced the `:terminal` command, which launches a terminal in a new editor pane.

Is there a way to identify these shells launched from vim vs. regular shells launched by xterm/urxvt/gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Since [Vim patch 8.1.049](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/d7a137fb0d980545dd), Vim does export the `VIM_TERMINAL` environment variable with the value of `v:version`. Before that, you could only work around it by getting the process tree information or possibly but not fool-proof by testing for the `$VIM` and `$VIMRUNTIME` environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

#### General approach with `ps`

You need to investigate if the parent process of the shell is `vim`. This works in my Debian 9:

```
pid=1234                              # specify PID of the shell in question
ps -o comm= "$(ps -o ppid= "$pid")"
```

where `ps -o ppid= "$pid"` returns the parent process ID. Note if there is no process with PID of `$pid`, the whole command will become `ps -o comm= ""` which is invalid and will throw an error.

This assumes you know the right PID. E.g. you can iterate over the output of `pidof bash`:

```
for pid in $(pidof bash); do ps -o comm= "$(ps -o ppid= "$pid")" 2>/dev/null; done
```

---

#### From within the shell itself

Within the shell *itself* the right PID is `$$`, so the above simplifies to

```
ps -o comm= "$(ps -o ppid= "$$")"   # non-optimal though, see below
```

But there is also `$PPID`. It is set by the shell to the value of its parent process ID during initialization of the shell. Therefore this should be almost equivalent:

```
ps -o comm= "$PPID"
```

Almost, because in general if the parent process dies and the shell survives (this is possible), the orphaned shell will get a new parent. This will be reflected by `ps -o ppid= "$$"` but not by `echo "$PPID"`, I think. In your case the discrepancy shouldn't matter, because:

1. If the shell survives, despite the two approaches yielding different results, none of the results will be `vim`, so the final conclusion will be "not a vim terminal" anyway.
2. I expect `vim` to kill shells started with `:terminal` when it exits (I cannot confirm this at the moment though), so the above point is irrelevant.
3. I expect any interactive shell to exit by itself when it loses its controlling terminal; so even if the previous expectation is wrong or only `vim` is forcefully killed (so it cannot send signals to its children), the shell will exit anyway. So the above points are irrelevant.

Therefore I think it's safe to assume the approaches with and without `$PPID` are equivalent in practice.

---

Note depending on your setup and how you started `vim`, `ps -o comm= ...` may not return the literal `vim` string. E.g. it may be `vim.basic`, `vim.gtk3` or something else.